# Shopify Webhooks: How do I run JavaScript when a Webhook is triggered?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, shopify, webhooks

**I want to setup a Shopify Webhook on the Order Cancellation event that will cause some javascript code to be run.**

In this specific case, **I want to send a negative transaction to Google Analytics** to remove the transaction when an order is cancelled (as described here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en )

I have my callback url / page setup (PHP) and it works correctly when loaded in a browser. But the webhook apparently *(obviously?)* does not trigger any client side code to run.

Any ideas on how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this does not solve the question specifically (of running javascript via a webhook) an alternative solution for this **specific** case would be to use Server Side Google Analytics tracking to send the negative transaction:

- https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-ga
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/